# Fatal Error and Crash when clicking add button in first Kotlin/Android APP

Tags: android, kotlin, crash

---

Please let me know how I can share the zip of my project should you feel like and be interested in seeing the full story

Also note that the suggested posts when I was making this one did not match my issue

---

Hello! I've tried many resources online and can't seem to get this figured out. Basically, I have a basic app to make for a class, a weird version of a calculator to get the hang of things. I've sent a message to the instructor and just waiting on a response, but I wanted to see what I could find out here.

The Problem: I can click and enter a number in each textview, but when I choose an operator (in this case, add) the whole app crashes.

The MainActivity.kt code is:

```
package com.example.lab01

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.view.View
import android.widget.Button
import android.widget.TextView

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        // variable declarations
        val n1=(findViewById<View>(R.id.Number1))
        val n2=(findViewById<View>(R.id.Number2))
        val result:TextView = findViewById(R.id.result_view)
        val add:Button = findViewById(R.id.button_add)
        // val subtract:Button = findViewById(R.id.button_subtract)
        // val multiply:Button = findViewById(R.id.button_multiply)
        // val divide:Button = findViewById(R.id.button_divide)

        // operator functions
        add.setOnClickListener {
            val sumResult = n1.toString().toDouble() + n2.toString().toDouble()
            result.text = sumResult.toString()
        }
    }
}
```

and the XML is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Calculator App"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.498"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.148" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/Number1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="100dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="75dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="Enter number 1"
        android:inputType="numberDecimal"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView2" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/Number2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="100dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="Enter number 2"
        android:inputType="numberDecimal"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/Number1" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button_divide"
        android:layout_width="99dp"
        android:layout_height="52dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="18dp"
        android:text="/"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/button_multiply"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/button_subtract" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button_multiply"
        android:layout_width="96dp"
        android:layout_height="52dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="100dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="18dp"
        android:text="*"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/button_subtract" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button_add"
        android:layout_width="99dp"
        android:layout_height="52dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="100dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
        android:text="+"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/Number2" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button_subtract"
        android:layout_width="101dp"
        android:layout_height="51dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="15dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
        android:text="-"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/button_add"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/Number2" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/result_view"
        android:layout_width="205dp"
        android:layout_height="73dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="100dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="120dp"
        android:text="The Result"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

The error? When I choose the add operator (the only thing I have coded rn), I get this:

```
2023-03-27 11:08:42.127  4229-4229  AndroidRuntime          com.example.lab01                    D  Shutting down VM
2023-03-27 11:08:42.134  4229-4229  AndroidRuntime          com.example.lab01                    E  FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                                                    Process: com.example.lab01, PID: 4229
                                                                                                    java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatEditText{1c90a17 VFED..CL. ........ 275,535-855,659 #7f080007 app:id/Number1 aid=1073741824}"
                                                                                                        at sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.readJavaFormatString(FloatingDecimal.java:2043)
                                                                                                        at sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.parseDouble(FloatingDecimal.java:110)
                                                                                                        at java.lang.Double.parseDouble(Double.java:538)
                                                                                                        at com.example.lab01.MainActivity.onCreate$lambda$0(MainActivity.kt:25)
                                                                                                        at com.example.lab01.MainActivity.$r8$lambda$ojjibajGvJUUhz9EAknQBAVC96s(Unknown Source:0)
                                                                                                        at com.example.lab01.MainActivity$$ExternalSyntheticLambda0.onClick(Unknown Source:6)
                                                                                                        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:7448)
                                                                                                        at com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton.performClick(MaterialButton.java:1131)
                                                                                                        at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:7425)
                                                                                                        at android.view.View.access$3600(View.java:810)
                                                                                                        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:28305)
                                                                                                        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)
                                                                                                        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
                                                                                                        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
                                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656)
                                                                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592)
                                                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)
```

I appreciate any and all help you can give. Thank you!

When I hit the add button (the only function I have written so far) the whole thing crashes. I've tried googling many different things and I just can't find anything specific to my issue. It seems there are a lot of versions of Kotlin with different syntax. I originally had compile errors but was able to find modern syntax that allowed compile. The app runs, but once I try to click add, the app crashes hard.

Comment: `n1.toString()` returns the string representation of the `EditText`, not the value of the text within the EditText.

Answer (score 1):

You are type casting in a wrong way. First we need to cast to text, than to string. You can try this

```
add.setOnClickListener {
        val sumResult = n1.text.toString().toDouble() + 
        n2.text.toString().toDouble()
        result.text = sumResult.toString()
    }
```